# how to have lightgray interface from kde to ubuntu

Tags: unity, themes, kde

I want to give all my apps a light-gray interface without actually installing KDE or Kubuntu. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Is there a theme or something that can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme you are looking for it called Oxygen. However, you'd be better off using a theme such as Evolve:

http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Evolve-GTK3-Theme-264780816

Oxygen would require some extra dependencies which you probably don't want.

To install Evolve:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:satyajit-happy/themes
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install evolve-gtk-theme
```